# Derby database unknow container format

Tags: java, derby

I'm building an app with java that use a DerbyDB with database.
So this app works from 2 years ago but now if I try to open this application, I have this strange error:

```
DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MyLog4J.java:45) - java.sql.SQLException: Formato contenitore sconosciuto nel contenitore null : 1.701.080.940
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.manager.impl.DescrizioneManagerImpl.getDescrizioniRiscossione(DescrizioneManagerImpl.java:48)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.Panel.PanelSpesaCliente.inizializzaLabelAndText(PanelSpesaCliente.java:874)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.Panel.PanelSpesaCliente.creaSwing(PanelSpesaCliente.java:132)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.esp.TestaFrame.attaccoframe(TestaFrame.java:52)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.esp.TestaFrame.<init>(TestaFrame.java:45)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.esp.TestaFrame$1.run(TestaFrame.java:65)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Formato contenitore sconosciuto nel contenitore null : 1.701.080.940
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB2: Formato contenitore sconosciuto nel contenitore null : 1.701.080.940
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeaderFromArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer4.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.setIdent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.xact.Xact.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.index.B2IFactory.readConglomerate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.conglomCacheFind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.findExistingConglomerate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.openScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndexMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndex(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.finishTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptorIndex1Scan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getUncachedTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.NameTDCacheable.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

what is the problem?

The problem is not the java application but I have this error when I try to do a query (all query) on the database

This is the derbt.log

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-18 09:54:18.829 GMT:
 Avvio Derby versione The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.5.3.0 - (802917): istanza a816c00e-0159-b0ff-9bd1-000000b64828
su directory database C:\Users\michele.castriotta\workspace\Commercialista\provaDb  

Programma di caricamento classe database avviato - derby.database.classpath=''
2017-01-18 09:54:22.451 GMT Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] (XID = 205124), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = provaDb), (DRDAID = null), Cleanup action starting
2017-01-18 09:54:22.451 GMT Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] (XID = 205124), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = provaDb), (DRDAID = null), Failed Statement is: SELECT DESCRIZIONE FROM DESCRIZIONERISCOSSIONE
ERROR XSDB2: Formato contenitore sconosciuto nel contenitore null : 1.701.080.940
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeaderFromArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer4.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.setIdent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.xact.Xact.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.index.B2IFactory.readConglomerate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.conglomCacheFind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.findExistingConglomerate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.openScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndexMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndex(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.finishTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptorIndex1Scan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getUncachedTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.NameTDCacheable.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.manager.impl.DescrizioneManagerImpl.getDescrizioniRiscossione(DescrizioneManagerImpl.java:48)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.Panel.PanelSpesaCliente.inizializzaLabelAndText(PanelSpesaCliente.java:874)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.Panel.PanelSpesaCliente.creaSwing(PanelSpesaCliente.java:133)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.esp.TestaFrame.attaccoframe(TestaFrame.java:52)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.esp.TestaFrame.<init>(TestaFrame.java:45)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.esp.TestaFrame$1.run(TestaFrame.java:65)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

2017-01-18 09:54:22.486 GMT:
Arresto istanza a816c00e-0159-b0ff-9bd1-000000b64828
----------------------------------------------------------------
Cleanup action completed
----------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-18 09:54:23.045 GMT:
 Avvio Derby versione The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.5.3.0 - (802917): istanza a02ac013-0159-b0ff-9bd1-000000b64828
su directory database C:\Users\michele.castriotta\workspace\Commercialista\provaDb  

Programma di caricamento classe database avviato - derby.database.classpath=''
2017-01-18 09:54:23.083 GMT Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] (XID = 205134), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = provaDb), (DRDAID = null), Cleanup action starting
2017-01-18 09:54:23.083 GMT Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] (XID = 205134), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = provaDb), (DRDAID = null), Failed Statement is: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clienti
ERROR XSDB2: Formato contenitore sconosciuto nel contenitore null : 1.701.080.940
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeaderFromArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer4.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.setIdent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RAFContainer.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.xact.Xact.openContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.index.B2IFactory.readConglomerate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.conglomCacheFind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.findExistingConglomerate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.openScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndexMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndex(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.finishTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptorIndex1Scan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getUncachedTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.NameTDCacheable.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at esempio.Visualizzazioni.eseguiQuery(Visualizzazioni.java:83)
    at Panel.PanelNorth.aggiornaTextClienti(PanelNorth.java:203)
    at Panel.PanelNorth.PanelNord(PanelNorth.java:54)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.Panel.PanelSpesaCliente.creaSwing(PanelSpesaCliente.java:158)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.esp.TestaFrame.attaccoframe(TestaFrame.java:52)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.esp.TestaFrame.<init>(TestaFrame.java:45)
    at com.mcsolution.commercialista.esp.TestaFrame$1.run(TestaFrame.java:65)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

2017-01-18 09:54:23.090 GMT:
Arresto istanza a02ac013-0159-b0ff-9bd1-000000b64828
----------------------------------------------------------------
Cleanup action completed
```

Comment: Is this an existing database? Or one that you've created brand-new? 10.5 is a **very** old version of Derby. Is there any chance that you opened the database with a newer version of Derby, then tried to go back to an older version?

Comment: No this is an existing database. How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps your database became damaged. When was the last time you used it successfully? Do you have a backup? Did your computer crash recently? Is your disk full?

Comment: the computer is not crash and the disk is not full. The last time is 16/01/2017, in this time the program works correctly

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kind of out of suggestions. Something unusual is going on. You shouldn't get an exception like that unless your database is damaged or you've found a bug somehow. Can you open up your database with a standard JDBC query tool like SquirrelSQL or Derby's IJ? Can you package up your database in a way that you can file it as a job in the Derby issue tracker so that the Derby developers can reproduce the problem you're seeing and analyze it?

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton, thanks for your answer. Can you indicate me a link to contact derby developer?

Comment: Here's the Derby community site: http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_comm.html